# Web-app on iOS8 doesn't transfer Touch events to iFrames

Tags: javascript, iframe, ios8, touch, ios-web-app

In a **web-app**, on **iOS 8.1**, **touch events** *(touchstart, touchend, etc.)* don't seems to be transferred to **iFrames**, but on the same device in Safari they are.
I tested the same web-app on **iOS 7** and again, the touch events are transferred to the iFrame perfectly. 
So basically, the problem seems to be directly related to iOS 8.
Unfortunately, I didn't found any documentation on the subject.
Anyone have encounter the same problem, found a workaround or know if there is an official bug report?
Thanks